# dynamic inheritance function

Tags: python, oop, recursion, inheritance

I am new do python OOP.

I have a problem that I can't solve by myself and even after hours of consulting the internet I am not a single step closer to an solution.

I have a linear class hierarchy where classes inherit parent classes.

For example:

```
class Animal:
    food = "everything"

class Carnivore(Animal) :
    food = "flesh"

class Wolf(Carnivore) :
    food = "big animals"

class Dog(Wolf) :
    food = "dog food"
```

Pretty simple. Each class is inheriting from another class and has the same attribute, which gets overwritten each time.

Now I want a single function, to get all the values of food.

This function should be recursive.
I am thinking of something like this :

```
def get_food(self) :
        print(self.food)
        super().get_food()
```

Which then can be called like:

```
Dog.get_food()
```

The problem is, that the instance using the function never changes. This means I will always get "dog food" as an answer.

Is there any way to iterate throuhg all parent classes with a single function and get their attribute?

I dont want the same function written in all classes with a statement like:

```
print(Wolf.food)
```

For a easier maintenance.

Many thanks for any help or advice.

Edit:

The expected outcome for the call:

```
Dog.get_food()
```

would be :

```
dog food
big animals
flesh
everything
```

Answer (score 2):

Hopefully I understood what you want to do correctly.

The only way I know how to do this is really tricky and you have to dive into the guts of python. You have to utilize the [Method Resolution Order](https://www.educative.io/answers/what-is-mro-in-python).

But be careful MRO can get really tricky in more complex examples and I don't suggest doing this in production code, EVER. But all that said it is a cool a thing to learn.

Essentially what this code does is it loops through the all the classes you inherit from and prints out the food property of that class.

```py
class Animal:
    food = "everything"
    def get_food(self):
        for _class in self.__class__.__mro__[:-1]:
            print(_class.food)
...

class Dog(Wolf):
    food = "dog food"

d = Dog()
d.get_food()
```

Note that we don't loop through the last class in the MRO because that is the generic object class and it doesn't have the food property.

Output:

```
dog food
big animals
flesh
everything
```

Comment: Why not just `print(_class.food)`?

Comment: @matszwecja you're completely right, also I am kinda dumb and didn't actually create a copy but a reference and changed the class of the original object... One second let me correct this

Comment: this is what i was looking for :) many thanks, but one more question: Is there a solution you would use in production?

Comment: @Blowsh1t redesign your classes so you don't need to do that at all.

Comment: @Blowsh1t I really don't have enough experience in production to recommend anything for this other than structuring the code in a way that doesn't put you in a situation like this.

Comment: Ok, maybe I have to think through my concept again, but for now thank u very very much.